# Load Firefox bookmarklet as normal URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I've just created a simple [bookmarklet](https://github.com/l0b0/bookmarklets/blob/master/yesterday.js) to load a URL containing a generated string. Is it possible to make this bookmarklet work like a normal bookmark:

- When left-clicking opens in the current tab.
- When middle-clicking opens in a new tab.
- After putting in a folder, when selecting Open All in Tabs opens in a new tab.

The first works, but the second does the same as the first, and the third results in just `javascript:...` in the location bar.

Edit: Could be related to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138198) reported *nine years ago*. Is there some way to work around it?

Comment: [The bookmarklet](https://github.com/l0b0/bookmarklets/blob/master/yesterday.js).

Comment: But there is no distinction of buttons in a bookmark. The browser will not communicate to your what button was used. - however in Fx6 I see the bookmarklet open in a new tab on clicking the scroll wheel. Open all in tabs also  seems to work in Fx

Comment: The bug is still marked as open, so I really doubt that we're talking about the same thing here.

Comment: Worked for me in Fx6 on 3 different bookmarklets

Comment: Can anyone confirm this? I won't be moving to Firefox 6 any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try putting your JavaScript code in a separate page saved on your computer somewhere, then bookmark that instead.